# how to iterate an Array which is AnyObject optional in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, loops, option-type

```
for driver: AnyObject in DataCache.drivers! {
    if (driver.id == id) {
            return driver;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get a compiler error? What is the error message?

Comment: Error in line 2 : (String, JSon) does not have a member named 'subscript'

Comment: What is the definition of DataCache.drivers?

Comment: {
        "id": 123,
        "name": "ravi",
        "currentVehicle": {
            "id": 144241,
            "vrn": "ML57CEU3"
        },
        "email": "r.r@gmail.com",
        "telephone": "07476828399",
        "mobile": null,
        "licenseNumber": "123",
        "licensePoints": 0,
        "notes": null,
        "fobIds": []
    }

Comment: I want to access driver.name  using driver.id

Comment: Looks like DataCache drivers is not a collection. To be sure, please paste the declaration of DataCache.drivers, not the content.

Comment: what is best way to convert my JSON object into ? in order to access driver.name or anything else using driver.id

Comment: RestApiManager.sharedInstance.getDriverList{ json in
            DataCache.drivers = json
        }

Comment: static var drivers : JSON?

Comment: DataCache is class name

Comment: @Raj drivers is not collection type. Your question make no sense. But i have write how to use it bellow. Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Your DataCache.drivers is `json`. Your need to parse it, using `NSJSONSerialization`. See code bellow.

```
let js = "{ \"id\": 123, \"name\": \"ravi\", \"currentVehicle\": { \"id\": 144241, \"vrn\": \"ML57CEU3\" }, \"email\": \"r.r@gmail.com\", \"telephone\": \"07476828399\", \"mobile\": null, \"licenseNumber\": \"123\", \"licensePoints\": 0, \"notes\": null, \"fobIds\": [] } "

if let data = js.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true) 
{
    let dict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.allZeros, error: nil) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

    let id = dict["id"]
    print("your id: \(id)")
}
```

Hope that help!

Comment: i am getting an error on line 2: cannot invoke dataUsingEncoding with an argument list of type(UNit, allowlossyConversion: Bool

Comment: @Raj Open your `PlayGround` and test my code. It's work.

Comment: Cast `DataCache.drivers ` as `String` first. See my example. I assume `js` is `DataCache.drivers `.

Comment: It works playground but it is not working in my code.  it give error JSON does not have member dataUsingEncoding

Comment: i have replaced js with my json object

Comment: func loadDriversREST()  {
        RestApiManager.sharedInstance.getDriverList{ json in
            var drivers = json
            
            if let data = drivers.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
            {
                let dict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.allZeros, error: nil) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
                
                let id = dict["id"]
                print("your id: \(id)")
            }
            
        }
    }

Comment: i am copying my whole function here

Comment: func loadDriversREST()  {
        RestApiManager.sharedInstance.getDriverList{ json in
            var drivers  = json
            
            if let data = drivers.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
            {
                let dict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.allZeros, error: nil) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
                
                let id = dict["id"]
                print("your id: \(id)")
            }
            
        }
    }

Comment: drivers :  {
        "id": 124,
        "name": "vitalii",
        "currentVehicle": {
            "id": 144239,
            "vrn": "MT62VLB"
        },
        "email": "v.r@gmail.com",
        "telephone": "07713208946",
        "mobile": null,
        "licenseNumber": "124841",
        "licensePoints": 0,
        "notes": null,
        "fobIds": []
    }

Comment: @Raj `json in var drivers = json` i don't know this `syntax`. What do you want here?

Comment: I am using SwiftJSON lib.... to call RESTFUL api driver ..... by doing above will produce driver = JSON object

Comment: @Raj I see. But your json not a collection type. You can't use loops here!.

Comment: @Raj Your `json` is `Dictionary`.